# Unable to publish workflow from SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: 2019, workflow-manager, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have SharePoint 2019 on premise environment consisting of an APP + Web servers. I am trying to publish a simple SharePoint 2013 workflow but getting following error:

```
System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException: The HTTP service located at http://APPServer:32843/a81ee7e967be4165b9ada2b6bc67fc4a/AppMng.svc is unavailable.  This could be because the service is too busy or because no endpoint was found listening at the specified address. Please ensure that the address is correct and try accessing the service again later. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

Workflow Manager is installed on Web server and when I go to Workflow Manager proxy in CA then it shows `Workflow is connected`. How do I go about diagnosing and fixing this issue because may be workflow manager is not properly installed? Here's the current setup:

On APP server `SharePoint Search Host Controller` service is running in services.msc

On Web server `SharePoint Search Host Controller` is in disabled state. Trying to start it using same account which is being used on App server throws error that Windows cannot start service.

Both App Management and Subscriptions Settings service applications are started. App management service is running on both App and Web server.

How to fix the issue? By the way why the URL in error above even points to App server. Shouldn't it point to Web server because this is where Workflow Manager is installed!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found and fixed the issue. The account under which AppManagementServicePool was running (in IIS application pools) didn't have proper permission. I changed it to a different account and now I am able to publish workflows.

Because as soon as I published the workflow, this particular application pool would stop. But the name being shown in IIS is not user friendly and it is something like 6d7ef89da........ so to find out I ran following command in SharePoint power shell.

> Get-SPServiceApplicationPool | Select Name, ID

This gave me name of the pool which is AppmanagementServicePool so I changed its account in IIS.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the **503 Service Unavailable** means the Application Pool was stopped! So you have first to check the status of the App pool "`WorkflowMgmtPool`" for `Workflow Management Site`.

- If it was stopped, try to restart it.
- Even it was started, I would suggest providing its Identity credential again and restarting it.

**Besides that**, I would suggest

- Checking the health checklist for the workflow manager at **[Workflow Manager Health Checklist for SharePoint 2019](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/workflow-manager-health-checklist-in-sharepoint/)** to ensure all related services are up and running.
- **[Re-register SharePoint Workflow Manager Service.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/reregister-sharepoint-workflow-manager-service/)**

> Also, review the workflow installation and configuration steps as mentioned at **[Install and Configure Workflow Manager SharePoint 2019 Step by Step](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/configure-workflow-manager-sharepoint-2016/)**